# Contract address is not shown in rinkeby testnet etherscan

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I am using Getch with truffle framework and i created an account. I have Migrations and Election.sol. After i can migrate, i couldnt see it in etherscan website. Although truffle migrate --reset --network rinkeby returns saving artifacts and contract addresses, why i cant see it on website?

geth --datadir ../eth_node --nodiscover console --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal" --cache=1024 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --networkid=4 --"allow-insecure-unlock" --mine --minerthreads 1

truffle.config

```
  rinkeby: {
   host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
   port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
   network_id: "4",       // Any network (default: none) (Rinkeby's id 
                             is given)
  from:"address",
  gas: 3000000
```

OUTPUT:

## Starting migrations...

> Network name:    'rinkeby'
>   Network id:      4
>   Block gas limit: 8000000

## 1_initial_migration.js

Deploying 'Migrations'

---

> transaction hash:    HASH
>   Blocks: 0            Seconds: 536
>   contract address:    0xd31433a447b2C64d979e15D4CD190098DA1044Ad
>   account:             ADDRESS
>   balance:             79228162514.252941273543950335
>   gas used:            284908
>   gas price:           20 gwei
>   value sent:          0 ETH
>   total cost:          0.00569816 ETH
>
> Saving artifacts
>
> ---
>
> Total cost:          0.00569816 ETH

## 2_deploy_contracts.js

Replacing 'Election'

---

> transaction hash:    HASH
>   Blocks: 1            Seconds: 4
>   contract address:    0xD6F5BF2E4eC20FB4DEf44d77FEBF84E96e680DFe
>   account:             ADDRESS
>   balance:             79228162514.246021893543950335
>   gas used:            345969
>   gas price:           20 gwei
>   value sent:          0 ETH
>   total cost:          0.00691938 ETH
>
> Saving artifacts
>
> ---
>
> Total cost:          0.00691938 ETH

## Summary

> Total deployments:   2
>   Final cost:          0.01261754 ETH
>
> contract address:    0xd31433a447b2C64d979e15D4CD190098DA1044Ad
>
> contract address:    0xD6F5BF2E4eC20FB4DEf44d77FEBF84E96e680DFe
>    }

When i use this following function

```
   function checkAllBalances() { 
     var i =0; 
      eth.accounts.forEach( function(e){
      console.log("  eth.accounts["+i+"]: " +  e + " \tbalance: " + 
       web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(e), "ether") + " ether"); 
        i++; 
       })
     };
```

It returns balance: 79228162514.246021893543950335 ether

What is wrong in my configuration?

Election.sol

```
 pragma solidity 0.5.8;

 contract Election {
  // Model a Candidate
      struct Candidate {
      uint id;
      string name;
      uint voteCount;
 }

 // Read/write Candidates
 mapping(uint => Candidate) public candidates;
// Store Candidates Count
uint public candidatesCount;

 constructor() public {
  addCandidate("Candidate 1");
   addCandidate("Candidate 2");
 }

 function addCandidate (string  memory _name) private {
     candidatesCount ++;
     candidates[candidatesCount] = Candidate(candidatesCount, _name, 0);
 }
```

}

Migrations.sol

```
  pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

  contract Migrations {
  address public owner;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  constructor() public {
   owner = msg.sender;
  }

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
    }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }

   function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
   }
   }
```

> eth.getBlock(0) returns

{
  difficulty: 1,
  extraData: "0x00",
  gasLimit: 4712389,
  gasUsed: 0,
  hash: "hash",
  logsBloom: "",
  miner: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  mixHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  nonce: "0x0000000000000042",
  number: 0,
  parentHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  receiptsRoot: "",
  sha3Uncles: "",
  size: 504,
  stateRoot: "",
  timestamp: 0,
  totalDifficulty: 1,
  transactions: [],
  transactionsRoot: "",
  uncles: []
}

> 

genesis.json

```
                {
"config": {
    "chainId": 88888,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0
},
"coinbase" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"difficulty" : "0x1",
"extraData" : "0x00",
"gasLimit" : "0x47e7c5",
"nonce" : "0x0000000000000042",
"timestamp" : "0x00",
"alloc" :{
    "address": {"balance": "0xffffffffffffffffffffffff"}
}
```

}

Comment: How do you launch geth? It appears you are deploying to another network. Do you have ganache running?

Comment: @Ismael I am using getch, not installed ganache. geth --datadir ../eth_node --nodiscover console --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal" --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --networkid=4 --"allow-insecure-unlock"  --mine --minerthreads 1

Comment: I created console.sh and inside of that                                                               
geth --datadir ../eth_node --nodiscover console --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal" --cache=1024 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --networkid=4 --"allow-insecure-unlock" --mine --minerthreads 1

Comment: and also i can use geth attach ../eth_node/geth.ipc this command @Ismael

Comment: @Ismael I am working in Oracle Virtual Box Ubuntu.It can be a problem?

Comment: You can edit your own question to add more detail. Working with VBox should not be an issue (I'm working with it too). What do you get if you execute `eth.getBlock(0)` in geth console? For me it looks like you are running a private network and not the real Rinkeby, it is PoA so only validators can mine, also the high balance.

Comment: @Ismael I edited my question in detail and also i added genesis.json file, trufle.config, my contracts.sol.  The output of eth.getBlock(0) is also added now. Arent they correct? What should i fix in my configuration for deploying rinkeby test network or how can i follow it if it is private network because ı didnt install ganache?

Answer (score 0):

You are not on the official rinkeby network. It [genesis block](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/block/0) has hash `0x6341fd3daf94b748c72ced5a5b26028f2474f5f00d824504e4fa37a75767e177`.

Several other fields are different:

- nonce is `0x0000000000000000`
- gasLimit `4700000`
- genesis.json is much bigger

To correctly setup Rinkeby you can follow the instructions in their page https://www.rinkeby.io/#geth.

Comment: for that should i install full node because i didnt install full node

Comment: In that page there are instructions to configure a light node. Since you are using truffle you can configure it to use an Infura url. Go to infura.io sign up and you will be given an URL to use to connect. In Truffle documentation they provide instructions how to configure for Infura. If you have more doubts search in the answered questions or create a new one.